# LessCSS after render event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm developing a website using LessCSS for stylesheet generation. As my co-workers have little-to-no knowledge of ant tasks (Ant + Rhino + Less) or NodeJS I put up a system that can swap between CSS and LessCSS, rendering the stylesheet through the client side library.

Trouble comes when I have to incorporate external libraries that rely on computed layout (i.e. [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)), they don't wait for the stylesheet to be compiled and therefore the graphic result is incorrect.

I'm trying to understand if exists an event that fires whenever Less finishes to compile the Css and shows it (the equivalent for jQuery's `$(document).ready()`). Is there anything I can rely on? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should definitely precompile your LESS into CSS when going for production. Also when working on dev systems you can use watchers or systems that automatically compile your LESS on file save.

Comment: Yes I know, I didn't want to force my co-workers to install NodeJS.
They found [Crunch](http://crunchapp.net/), so they worked around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you can load the LESS script (before other external libraries) with the Async option set to true. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    less = {async: true};
</script>
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="another.external.library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or maybe, if LESS has a callback function, you can place the external lib call there.

Comment: I think it's the async option that's causing this problem, because the less css stylesheets are compiled looooooong after the document ready event (when I wrote this question I was already using that option). I'll try without the async option next monday.